# Add 1 hour on mysql timestamp in php

Tags: php

In my Mysql table I have a timestamp field.
In my php page I show the record ($row[data]) in this way

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['data']));
```

Now in my php I'd like to add 1 hour on my date.
How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['data'])+3600);
```

note that you **can't** compare resulting dates in "d-m-Y" format.

either compare `strtotime` results or initial dates. or format your results into proper format first.

Comment: Thanks, but now I notice that I have another problem. If I compare $date1 and $date2(date1 +3600) the result is wrong.. You can tell me why? `$date1 > $date2` return TRUE! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could do this straight away in MySQL:

```
SELECT `date` + INTERVAL 1 HOUR AS `date`
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
         echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['data'].' +1 hour'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
strtotime($row['data'] . ' +1 hour')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['data']) + 3600);
```

Just add the time manually (3600 seconds = 1 hour).

Answer (score 0):

Add 3600 seconds and you will be fine.

```
echo date("d-m-Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['data'])+3600);
```